# Can We Pass Multiple Parameters to RestCypherQueryEngine.query?

Tags: java, email, neo4j, cypher, spring-data

I want to implement a log in portal using java, neo4j REST API and Spring Framework. I am using the RestCypherQueryEngine class to send a cypher query to the server.

The query looks like -->

`String query = "MATCH n WHERE n.Email = {email} AND n.Password = {pass} RETURN n;"
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query(query, Map.Util("Email", email), Map.Util("Password", pass);`
.
"email" and "pass" are both Strings with the respective values.

I wanted to know if this is a valid query and can two parameters be passed like this ?
and how to know if a node has been returned or not or if the the login is authenticated. ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all parameters into one map:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("email", email");
params.put("password", pass);
QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query(query,params);
```

**NB:** Query parameters are case sensitive.